# dimension of operations of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> $\text{If}\\ 
> W1= {(X,Y,Z | x+y-z=0 )},\\
> W2= {(X,Y,Z | 3x+y-2z=0 )},\\
> W3= {(X,Y,Z | x-7y+3z=0 )},\\
> \text{then find dim ($W_1\cap W_2 \cap W_3$ ) and dim ($W_1 + W_2 $).}
> $

is this correct answer ?

dim ($W_1\cap W_2 \cap W_3$ ) = 2 and base ($W_1\cap W_2 \cap W_3$ )= {(1,1,-1) (0,-2,1)}

dim  (W1 ) = 2 and
dim  (W2 ) = 2 and
dim ( W1 ∩ W2 )= 2 and 
base ( W1 ∩ W2 )= {(1,1,-1) (0,-2,1)}

Comment: If $v\in W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3$ then $v$ satisfies each of those equations, so $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&-1\\3&1&-2\\1&-7&3\end{bmatrix}v=0$$

Comment: You need to know what $W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3$ and $W_1+W_2$ are before considering dimension.

Comment: Now after converting to echelon form, we can find basis  & dimension for the same .

Comment: but don't we construct matrix like that for W1+W2 +W3 instead of  W1∩W2∩W3 ?

Comment: dim (W1 ∩ W2 ∩ W3) = 2 and base (W1 ∩ W2 ∩ W3 )= {(1,1,-1) (0,-2,1)}

dim (W1 ) = 2 and dim (W2 ) = 2 and dim ( W1 ∩ W2 )= 2 and base ( W1 ∩ W2 )= {(1,1,-1) (0,-2,1)}

Answer (score 1):

A column vector $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$ belongs to $W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3$ if and only if
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
3 & 1 & -2 \\
1 & -7 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Let's compute the RREF of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
3 & 1 & -2 \\
1 & -7 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & -8 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1/2 \\
0 & 1 & -1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This shows (justify it) that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1/2 \\ 1/2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
makes a basis for $W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3$.

This also shows (justify it) that $W_1\cap W_2=W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3$; thus
$$
\dim(W_1+W_2)=\dim W_1+\dim W_2-\dim(W_1\cap W_2)=\dots
$$

Comment: thnx..my approach was completely wrong..I just equated base= number of non zero rows after reducing to echelon form..

Comment: @chandan You have to find the null space, rather than the column space.

Comment: absolutely..thanks